# A Conjecture on this inequality which I couldn't solve.

Tags: inequality

This is my conjecture :
 Let $a_1\geq a_2 \geq\cdots\geq a_n$ be nonnegative rational numbers such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=1$. Then,

$$\sum_{1\leq i<j \leq n} a_ia_j(a_i+a_j)(1-a_i)(1-a_j)\leq\frac{27}{256}$$

with equality if and only if $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=\frac{1}{4}$
and $a_5=a_6=\cdots=a_n=0$

This problem confused me for a long time. Maybe it is wrong.
Any idea or solution of this problem would be wonderful for me.

Comment: Where does the problem come from? Why do you think that it is true?

Comment: To be exact,   it is  my conjecture.  I put it to test many times, it is true. It came from my research topic 4 months ago. Maybe I should modify the style of question.

Comment: $n=2$ is wrong.

Comment: @ToniMhax: Unless I am mistaken, it is $a_1 a_2 (1-a_1)(1-a_2) \le \frac {1}{16} < \frac{27}{256}$ in the case $n=2$.

Comment: yup my mistake tx